# TensorFlow metric: top-N accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics, top-n

I'm using [add_metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/add_metrics) trying to create a custom metric that computes top 3 accuracy for a classifier. Here's as far as I got:

```
def custom_metrics(labels, predictions):
   # labels => Tensor("fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo:422", shape=(?,), dtype=int64)
   # predictions => {
   #    'logits': <tf.Tensor 'dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0' shape=(?, 26) dtype=float32>,
   #     'probabilities': <tf.Tensor 'dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0' shape=(?, 26) dtype=float32>,
   #     'class_ids': <tf.Tensor 'dnn/head/predictions/ExpandDims:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=int64>,
   #     'classes': <tf.Tensor 'dnn/head/predictions/str_classes:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=string>
   #  }
```

Looking at the implementation of existing `tf.metrics`, everything is implemented using tf ops. How could I implement top 3 accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement it yourself `tf.nn.in_top_k` is very useful - it returns a boolean array which indicates if target is within the top k predictions. You just have to take the mean of the result:

```
def custom_metrics(labels, predictions):
    return tf.metrics.mean(tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions=predictions, targets=labels, k=3))
```

You can also import it:

```
from tf.keras.metrics import top_k_categorical_accuracy
```